# Google Cloud Run - Does it support non http protocol for inbound request or outbound requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have an existing application that I was trying to deploy it to google cloud run, but the application can't connect to an external NATS services.  It seems that cloud run only supports http, websockets, and gRPC for outbound connections and traffic.  It doesn't seem that an application can make a pure TCP/IP connection with binary data from a cloud run application.

Just looking for someone to confirm this.  I have not been able to find any documentations that explicitly states the inbound and outbound limitations of cloud run.

Note: my app can connect to REDIS though.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I did get it working, I had two issues.  The first was I deployed the nats image and not the nats-streaming image, and the second issue was the nats-streaming container needed to be in the same VPC as the cloud run  app and then it worked.  So you can connect to a NATS server from a Cloud Run App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no outbound protocol limitation.

In terms of inbound, Cloud Run only supports HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 (which includes gRPC) over TLS (HTTPS). That said, server-streaming is not supported (e.g. websockets or streaming gRPC calls).

Therefore, you cannot serve with arbitrary TCP wire protocols on Cloud Run.

Comment: Is there documentation that states there are no outbound protocol limitation?

Comment: Would connecting to NATS from a cloud run app violate the underlying tenants for an application running in cloud run?  Would that be considered a back ground running app since it may be processing messages from NATs that don't go through the google front end?

Comment: Thank you AhmetB for the information, there indeed doesn't seem to be any outbound protocol limitations from a Cloud Run App.   My issue was I needed to put the Cloud Run App and the nats-streaming container in the same VPC.

Answer (score 1):

Yes according with this [document](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#grpc_websocket), Cloud Run just support HTTP, WebSockets and gRPC by the moment, also [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#http-methods) is pointed the http requests not supported, I suggest you create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), if the petition earns enough people popularity this feature can be added to Cloud Run

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation, but the documentation doesn't seem to be complete.  My cloud run application can connect to Redis which proves that outbound protocols other then Web and gRPC are supported.  Thanks for the suggestions on adding a feature request, if support for NATs from cloud run apps proves out to not be supported then I will add a feature request.

Comment: Documentation is enough clear: "Cloud Run (fully managed) currently does not support HTTP streaming. Therefore, inbound requests with protocols like WebSockets and gRPC streaming are not supported.

Cloud Run (fully managed) services support unary gRPC.

For outbound requests, both WebSockets and gRPC are supported."  In order to save time and avoid mistakes for the user documentation put clear how works Cloud Run