# Does GCP Cloud Run support HTTPS app protocol

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Is there an equivalent of

```
cloud.google.com/app-protocols: '{"http":"HTTPS"}'
```

for Cloud Run?

Certain third-party apps require TLS termination at the container level. Is there a recommendation for this scenario?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62535673/google-cloud-run-does-it-support-non-http-protocol-for-inbound-request-or-outb

Comment: At container level, only HTTP is supported. HTTPS layer is served by an upper layer (Google Front End). Doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#tls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not implement HTTPS at the container level. If that is a requirement, you will need to deploy a different service.

The container should not implement any transport layer security directly. TLS is terminated by Cloud Run for HTTPS and gRPC, and then requests are proxied as HTTP or gRPC to the container without TLS.

[Container runtime contract - TLS](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#tls)